# SFML Generate isometric tile

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, sfml

I have a sprite, a square, just for orthogonal projection. Now I want to project it in a very basic, simple isometric way. (I know this might not be pretty, but I just want to figure this out)

Given my square, I rotate it 45 degrees. Now if I understand correctly, I should still divide my height by 2. This has been impossible for me in SFML. There is a scale function but if I scale with a factor 0.5 in the y-axis direction, my cube just gets stretched, instead of a diamond shape. It looks as though SFML transforms the sprite according to it's own relative axes (that were rotated before..).

Since you cannot access the height of a sprite, I was wondering if this was even possible?

**Can I convert a square sprite to a diamond shape in SFML?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a sf::RenderTexture is an option (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180047/1801919)). Another option is to fiddle with the `sf::View`. Double the view's height, and adjust coordinates. It would go something like this:

```
my_sprite.setRotation(45.f);
//adjust the position for new screen coordinates (once)
my_sprite.setPosition(my_sprite.getPosition().x, my_sprite.getPosition().y * 2);

//...

//when drawing:
sf::View v = my_render_window.getDefaultView();
v.setSize(v.getSize().x, v.getSize().y * 2);
v.setCenter(v.getSize() *.5f);

my_render_window.setView(v);
my_render_window.draw(my_sprite);
my_render_window.setView(my_render_window.getDefaultView());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotate your sprite as you are doing now.  Render it to an [sf::RenderTexture](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php).  Use the member function [`getTexture`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php#a95bc5152c497066d31fdc57da8e17678), and make a new sprite from it, or reuse the old sprite.  Scale the sprite along the y-axis.  Draw it to the render window.

Some math on your part may be required in order to set the `RenderTexture` to the right size and to draw the original sprite in the correct location on it.

```
original_sprite.setRotation(45);
sf::RenderTexture rt;
rt.create(FigureOutWidth(),FigureOutHeight());
original_sprite.setPosition(MoreMathHere());
rt.draw(original_sprite);
sf::Sprite new_sprite(rt.getTexture());
new_sprite.setScale(1.0,0.5);
```

It should go without saying, but do this once in initialization, not every frame.

Comment: Another possibility is to change the `sf::View`'s size before drawing (double the height, and adjust the sprite's position accordingly).

Comment: @AndreiTita: Hey, yeah.  That works, and is much simpler.  I didn't know you could do that.  Why haven't you made an answer?